# How to get the Cell value of A1(Cell Address) using apache poi 3.6

Tags: apache-poi

I have Excel Cell Address like A1,A2. So, how to access this cell programatically using poi3.6

another way is

```
 row=mySheet.getRow();
 cell=row.getCell();
```

But i have the address in the format of A1 ... so, how do I access those cell programatically

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
row = mySheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```

See [Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) for more samples.

Answer (score 5):

There's a cellReference function

E.g.

CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3");

(taken from the [example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) here)

Answer (score 3):

(Code on Kotlin)

You have 2 options to specify cell address:

Option 1: by `CellReference` (which can contain reference to the sheet name):

```
val cellReference = CellReference("SheetName!C11")

val sheet = workbook.getSheet(cellReference.sheetName)
val row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.row)
val cell: Cell = row.getCell(cellReference.col.toInt())
```

Option 2: by `CellAddress` (which can only contain reference on the cell within a sheet):

```
val sheetName = "SheetName"
val cellAddress = CellAddress("C11")

val sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName)
val row = sheet.getRow(cellAddress.row)
val cell: Cell = row.getCell(cellAddress.column)
```

Unfortunately code can't be simpler because both `Workbook` and `Sheet` have no methods which return cell by the `CellReference` or `CellAddress`.

Note: `getCell()` overload with `MissingCellPolicy` parameter allows to write code in more safe manner:

```
val cell: Cell? = row.getCell(cellAddress.column, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL)
return cell ?: throw UnexpectedExcelStructureException("Unable to find $cellAddress cell on the $sheetName sheet or cell is empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] ar)
        {
            // char a = 'A', b = 'B';
            //string[] ab = new string[100];
            //ab[0]= "A1";
            int k = 0, h = 0; ;
            string ab = "B1";
            int l;
            l = Convert.ToInt32(ab.Length.To String());

            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                if(!char.Is Digit(ab[i]))
                { 
                for (int j = 65; j <= 90; j++)
                {
                if(Convert.ToInt32(ab[i])==j)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        k = 1-k;
                    }

                }

            }
                else
                {
                    h = (Convert.ToInt32(ab[i]))-49;

                }
                }

            Console.Write Line(l);
            Console.Write Line(h+""+k);



        }
    }}
```

replace variable 'ab' as your excel cell address